# Problems while installing Ubuntu on Asus TUF A15 Laptop / Gnu Grub 2.04

Tags: boot, grub2, asus

Today I was trying to install ubuntu on my Asus laptop currently running windows 10. I have flashed a drive with Ubuntu Iso file (the last version) and whenever I try to boot the Iso from the USB Drive it opens a terminal called Gnu Grub 2.04 and I can t get to the installer.
Please provide me some help. I need Ubuntu for my school.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider dual-booting instead of replacing Windows or even a Virtual Machine. For the former we also need to know which ISO are you trying to use and how did you made the installation media.

Answer (score 0):

If this what the installation medium displays:[image] that is the normal behavior, select `Install Ubuntu` or `Try Ubuntu` with the **arrow key** and press **enter**.

Then follow the procedure.

Comment: It doesn t say that. It says:BASH like line editing is supported and something with the TAB button if I remember

Comment: You have to be more precise... I suppose that you entered the `grub command line` so press `esc` to go back to the installation menu.

Comment: I didn t pressed anything. I don t have Ubuntu already installed on my device, i have windows and I wanted to install Ubuntu so i ll take it step by step on what I have done. 
1 Downloaded the Ubuntu Iso File
2 Flashed it to a USB drive
3 Booted it from my boot menu
4 It just opens this grub and says Minimal bash like line editing is supported for the first word, tab lists possible commands.

That s it